# Facebook javascript sdk working without ssl

Tags: javascript, facebook, ssl, facebook-javascript-sdk

I just spent the last day struggling regarding whether or not I can use facebook javascript sdk without ssl. The popup window I got from facebook was "some error accord", without farther explanation.

For me, this was a tricky one. On the one hand, some websites (including facebook developers) suggests that after Oct 11 ssl will be required for facebook apps. On the other, the examples in facebook developers remain compatible with both, http & https protocols.

Now I have found root cause. Hopefully it will help someone and save him/her some time....

The problem was under my facebook app "Site URL" definition. It was set to https protocol:

```
**https**://www.mysite.com/
```

Changing this to http solved the problem:

```
http://www.surf-space.com/
```

I can now (correct for March 21 2012) use the standard http protocol, no ssl is needed.

Answer (score 2):

SSL certificate is **only** required for [Apps on Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/).  You could still use the Javascript SDK on your website **without** the need of an SSL certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I would still recommend doing everything in SSL. While you may have found your way around this problem, Facebook and other providers are all switching to SSL only. You can get SSL certs for free at http://www.startssl.com or many other places. Just google free ssl.

There isn't much reason not to use SSL these days, the overheads are not that big. Plus once SPDY becomes more common SSL slow down won't really account for anything much.